# How to aggregate the elements in a struct in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
 "struct": [
  {
    "ele_1": "abcd",
    "ele_2": "1.0"
  },
  {
    "ele_1": "egf",
    "ele_2": "1.0"
  }
]
```

i have data like this in struct format , i am trying to get to something like
1st string_agg on ele_1 in a strut and then sum on ele_2, i have tried unnest( struct) but that is causing duplicated.

```
"ele_1": "abcd,egf",
"ele_2": "2.0"
```

Comment: I am just lost.  The second set of data seems to have values that are not in the first set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry , i have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an array of *records* and want to separately aggregate the fields:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(rec.ele_1)
        from unnest(t.record_array) rec
       ),
       (select sum(rec.ele_2)
        from unnest(t.record_array) rec
       )
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another [optimized] option below

```
select * except(struct_col),
  (select as struct 
    string_agg(ele_1) ele_1, 
    sum(ele_2) ele_2
  from t.struct_col
  ).*
from `project.dataset.table` t
```